# Non negative irreducible matrix times a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ be a real non negative irreducible matrix, meaning that $(a_{ij})\geq 0$ I know from a theorem in Minc's book that $(I+A)^{n-1}>0$.

It is also stated in the book that $B=(I+A)^{n-1}.A>0$. I am not convinced. How can I see this? 
Could it be that $B=(I+A)^{n-1}.A\geq 0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $B$ related to $A$?

Comment: The theorem I am trying to understand is that A is irreducible if and only if there's a number k such that $a_{ij}^k$ is greater than zero, where that denotes de ij element of $A^k$ I know that $B=(A+I)^n$

Comment: By $(I +A)^{n-1} > 0$ do you mean it is positive definite?

Comment: I mean all the entries of that matrix are positive.

Comment: If $C>0$ and $A$ is irreducible then $CA>0$.

Comment: Where can I find this? Or how can I prove it?

Comment: @Alfdav: Do you have a proof of this theorem (and seek an explanation to the details of the proof) or are you looking to find the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the $j$-column of $A$ by $a_{\ast j}$. As $A$ is irreducible and non-negative, $a_{\ast j}$ is not the zero vector and $a_{\ast j}\ge0$ entrywise. Since $B>0$, we get $Ba_{\ast j}>0$ for each $j$. Thus $BA>0$.